# How to use several string arguments in Python

Tags: python

I want to pass two parameters to my string, using % s.

I tried this, but it did not work :

```
title = "im %s with %s"
title % "programming" % "python"
```

it gives this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Do you have an idea?
thanks

Comment: This is something you answer by looking in the same place that you found out that there is a `%` operation in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is probably best understood by breaking down how these formatting directives work. The basic idea is that each `%` in a string means an argument needs to be subsequently supplied to the string.

For instance, this would work:

```
title = "i'm %s with %s" % ('programming', 'python')
```

and yield

```
"i'm programming with python"
```

The 's' in `%s` means that this is a place holder for a string. A 'd' would be for integers, 'f' for floats etc. There are also additional parameters you can specify. See [these docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations).

If you don't supply enough items for each place holder, it will result in the `not enough arguments for format string` message.

Your specific example first creates a string constant that has two formatting directives in it. Then when you use it, you'll have to supply two items for it.

In other words,

```
title = "i'm %s with %s"
title % ('programming', 'python')
```

becomes

```
"i'm %s with %s" % ('programming', 'python')
```

Answer (score 8):

The correct syntax is:

```
title = "im %s with %s"
title % ("programming", "python")
```

The `%` operator takes two operands:

1. the format string goes on the left-hand side;
2. the tuple containing all the arguments goes on the right-hand side (if there's only one parameter, it can be a scalar).

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer but:

You may also use something like:

```
title = "im %(doing)s with %(with)s"
title % {'doing': 'programming', 'with': 'python'}
```

or:

```
title = "im %(doing)s with %(with)s" % {'doing': 'programming', 'with': 'python'}
```

Where instead of %s you use %(your dictionary key)s and instead of a tuple you pass a dict after the modulo operator.

Check [String formatting operations](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations)