# variable in regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use several string arguments in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667605/how-to-use-several-string-arguments-in-python)

In the code below I'm trying to search for the one of the following patterns

1. href="any characters with one hypen in between except ?"
2. href="any characters with one hypen in between and if any other hypen, comes after ? "

I'm having problem where a variable must be inserted within regular expression twice.

**Code**:

```
mlink=re.findall('href="(%s+/[a-zA-Z0-9]+-[a-zA-Z0-9?=]+)"|href="(%s+/[a-zA-Z0-9]+-[a-zA-Z0-9]+[?]+[a-zA-Z0-9-]*)"' % path,contents)
```

Also,
I'm getting `not enough arguments for format string` error..

Comment: (Also, don't forget to [*quote* input to regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280435/escaping-regex-string-in-python) or you'll end up with special characters!)

Comment: Put parens around `path, contents`

Comment: It's fairly annoying to chase moving questions. Make sure the code posted is the *actual code* used that exhibits said errors .. -1 because [looking up the error message would have said what is wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+not+enough+arguments+for+format+string+error).

Comment: that is the code for which i m getting error and i have mentiion exact error that is displayed

Comment: (The code was changed, hence "moving" .. anyway, follow the above links.)

Answer (score 1):

instead of the % format operator,  you could use the string `format`function to put a variable in a string more than once

e.g.

```
 >>> '   {0}  {1}  {0}  '.format('foo', 'bar')
 '   foo  bar  foo  '
```

(the question isn't really about regex's!)

Comment: if i use format function it returns list of tuples i.e if first condition is satisfied second element will be empty... i want list of string ..can you help me on this..